# Using WebWoker with create-react-app and typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, create-react-app, web-worker

I'm having the project using `create-react-app` and `typescript`

I would like to enable `WebWorker` to do some expensive tasks. But I have not found any solutions to enable it.

I have looked through some libraries:

- https://github.com/developit/workerize-loader

Do you have any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I finally use [worker-loader]. It works OK.

https://github.com/webpack-contrib/worker-loader#integrating-with-typescript

To integrate with TypeScript, you will need to define a custom module for the exports of your worker

```
// typings/custom.d.ts
declare module "worker-loader!*" {
  class WebpackWorker extends Worker {
    constructor();
  }

  export default WebpackWorker;
}
```

```
// Worker.ts
const ctx: Worker = self as any;

// Post data to parent thread
ctx.postMessage({ foo: "foo" });

// Respond to message from parent thread
ctx.addEventListener("message", (event) => console.log(event));
```

```
// App.ts
import Worker from "worker-loader!./Worker";

const worker = new Worker();

worker.postMessage({ a: 1 });
worker.onmessage = (event) => {};

worker.addEventListener("message", (event) => {});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this!

Comment: To solve unexpected import error from eslint, use bottom code on top of the worker import:

// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-webpack-loader-syntax

Answer (score 0):

Answer for latest React Scripts (v5+) and Webpack 5:

The worker-loader module doesn't work for Webpack 5.

```js
const w = new Worker(new URL('path/to/your/worker.ts', import.meta.url));

w.postMessage('hello world');
```

See [Webpack docs](https://webpack.js.org/guides/web-workers/).